# Joomla - clone user on register

Tags: database, joomla, registration

I'm looking for a way to add Joomla user to custom table (PrestaShop - same database) - duplicate user on registration.
So user will be able to login to Joomla and second script (PrestaShop) using same login information.
Any ideas where I should start looking in Joomla files?
I know, that custom user plugin will be a better way to achive user duplication, but now I'm looking for temporary hard-coded fix until I'll be able to write a plugin.

(Joomla 1.6)

Comment: I would say you check JFusion http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-bridges/3723 but it's not compatible with 1.6 yet.

Comment: I've tried JFusion but with no success

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions won't let you save the passwords. If you are looking for saving the password as well then you will need to look into

components\com_user\controller.php 
function register_save() {}

Note: I have given with reference to joomla 1.5. It might slightly vary if you are using joomla 1.6